# Flutter - How can I create an Incoming Call Notification?

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I'm building an app that allows users to call eachother using the agora_rtc_engine.
I'm currently stuck trying to implement a notification system that will alert users when they receive a call.

I'm using Firebase Messaging for notifications.

I have the following questions:

1. How would I go about replacing the default notification card with a custom one that has buttons for answering or declining the call?
2. How can I specify the amount of time the notification stays on screen? An incoming call rings for about 30 seconds before closing, so I would like my notification card to appear on screen for that period of time.

I've been looking at the flutter_local_notifications, but they don't have a "incoming call" notification style.

Any piece of information is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: any solutions guys?

Comment: hey anything..?

Comment: Hi! Since I posted the question I've moved on from the project because I could not find any help.  I was able to start the Ringtone from background notifications and set the notification tap action to send the user to my incoming call page. Unfortunately it was a bad user experience and it wasn't working on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you trying to use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Check out the "Setting the lifespan of a message" section of the official documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl

There you will find an example of a cloud message with time_to_live parameter - it determines how long will the notification be active on the recipient's device.

Here is an example of a request that includes TTL (taken from the official documentation):

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    },
    "apns":{
      "headers":{
        "apns-expiration":"1604750400"
      }
    },
    "android":{
      "ttl":"4500s"
    },
    "webpush":{
      "headers":{
        "TTL":"4500"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a small snippet of code as example? Links can change.

Comment: I edited the answer - added a small snippet of code

Answer (score 0):

some time has passed since asking the question, that project went into hibernation but I’ve started another which also includes calling functionality. This time though I made it work.

How? Using a combination of packages:

1. agora: for the actual communication part - audio and video
2. flutter_callkit_incoming: this one helps with showing the call notifications on Android and iOS
3. a custom implementation of PushKit: I don’t have extensive documentation available for this one, but on iOS, to wake the device up form sleep when a notification is received, you can’t always rely on classic notifications (that come from firebase in my case). so instead, I generated a pushkit token for the user and modified the cloud function so that if a pushkit token exists, I’ll use the pushkit notification channel instead of firebase messaging channel. You can find more info in the pushkit documentation of flutter_callkit_incoming.

Hope this helps, good luck!